# Unable to Share Folder in Network

Tags: fileshare

I am attempting to create a folder share on a Windows Server 2012 R2 two-node cluster Hyper-V volume in the network and I'm getting these error messages:

An error occurred while trying to share FolderA.  The resources must be online on the same node for this operation.
The shared resource was not created at this time.

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that the clustered disk was not assigned to any clustered role. There was actually no role in *Roles* node in Failover Cluster Manager.
I needed to click *Configure Role*, select *File Server* role, (*File Server for general use*), name it somehow, and then select the clustered disk as the actual storage for this clustered role.
Now when I click newly created role, I can see the disk where I wanted to create shared folder within *Storage*. The shared folder is then available in network as "\clustered_role_name\folder_name"